# how to display all Rows duplicates and unduplicates id in crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports

When duplicates **Id** show only first duplicates number and don't display all duplicates.

> note : I'm use Crystal Report 2012 in VS 2012 and working create Group name fields for ID

```
  ID    names     
 ----   ---- 
  1     jon
  2     sam
  1     sas

Display in Crystal Report :

 ID    names     
 ----   ---- 
  1     jon
  2     sam
```

I want display all data duplicates or unduplicates

```
I want Display in Crystal Report :

  ID    names     
 ----   ---- 
  1     jon
  2     sam
  1     sas
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the group, if you created, and put all the column in detail section and just preview the report.

You definitely get the record same as you received.

Comment: how to remove group without remove text fields because if working remove group name fields he well remove text fields fro columns ?

Comment: group means group section.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a group by `Id` in your design and the fields are in the group section.

If so, just put the fields in details section and i will work. If it is not the case, please post a screenshot of your design.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to right click the

> Object --> common tab --> uncheck-> The suppress if duplicate